# Literal meaning of 去場 (Saruba)

Tags: meaning, kanji, readings, names

There is a place in Hokkaidō called Saruba 去場 (さるば)

What can be the literal meaning of this place name??

Comment: Literal meaning would be along the line of @HalfwayDillitante 's answer. Its origin, on the other hand, [seems to be Ainu](https://www.frpac.or.jp/event/direct/2018aynu_itak_ani_a=i=siramkire_kusu_ne/bus01.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「去る」　means to leave, depart, disappear from, etc. 「場」 means location, place.

So...I guess it would be something like "The place from which you depart".

I should note that 「去る」 has a connotation of being low-key, stealthy, etc. You wouldn't 去る a location or event with much fanfare.

As it has been noted, the origin of that name is Ainu, and in that case the meaning is equivalent to "A village located upstream from paddy fields". You will find many examples of such names in Hokkaido, where the Ainu people lived from a long time ago.

Source: [Millennium Village Project Webpage](http://mille-vill.org/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%EF%BC%BB%E6%B2%99%E6%B5%81%E9%83%A1%E5%B9%B3%E5%8F%96%E7%94%BA%E5%8E%BB%E5%A0%B4%EF%BC%BD)

Comment: Are we sure it's not from Ainu? It's not unusual for place names in Hokkaido to come from Ainu and then simply have ateji used for the kanji. If that's the case, it would be like saying 寿司 means "lifespan administrator".

Comment: The question was "What is the literal meaning of 【去場】?" so my answer is in response to that. You are 100% correct, the origin of that name is Ainu and means "Village located upstream from paddy fields". 

Source: http://mille-vill.org/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%EF%BC%BB%E6%B2%99%E6%B5%81%E9%83%A1%E5%B9%B3%E5%8F%96%E7%94%BA%E5%8E%BB%E5%A0%B4%EF%BC%BD

Comment: The question is "What can be the literal meaning of this place name??" which I would take to mean "the origin" regardless of how it's written. Like, the literal meaning of the place name "Fishkill, NY" is not "place to murder fish" even though it looks like that if you think of it as being English. But I see you edited the answer to include the origin information.

Comment: It's funny that you would mention Fishkill, I've driven through that area several times. As you are correct, I have corrected my answer to reflect the Ainu origins and actual meaning.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The literal meaning was what I needed, although it is also very interesting to know the meaning in Ainu. I didn't know the Millennium Village Project Webpage, but it is certainly a very useful site.